# Upload text file to Swagger with PUT request Java

Tags: java, rest, swagger, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am using Apache HttpConnection to send text file with PUT request, to server host on Swagger. It seems that i am missing something since as response i get "Internal Server Error". 
Code at client site:

```
    String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:XXXX/warehouse-ui/api/v2/external-file/IMPORT_RATIO?businessUnit=MBA&sourceSystem=AVALOQ_MBA&effectiveFrom=2011-12-21&effectiveTo=MAX&threshold=WARNING";       
    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((usrPassPair).getBytes());

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(myLocalFile);
    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("test", is, ContentType.create("multipart/form-data"), "asd.txt").build();
    request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Code at server site (Swagger):

```
@Path ("/{descriptor}")
@PUT
@Consumes ({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@ApiOperation (position = 1, value = "Uploads a file and transfers data according to given descriptor and for the specified effective date. Transfer is done synchronously.")
@Produces ("application/json")
public Response uploadFile (
        @QueryParam ("businessUnit") @ApiParam(required = true) String businessUnitName,
        @QueryParam ("sourceSystem") @ApiParam (required = true, value = "The source system") String sourceSystemName,
        @PathParam ("descriptor") @ApiParam (required = true, value = "The descriptor for the file") String descriptor,
        @QueryParam ("effectiveFrom") @ApiParam (required = true, value = "The date in ISO format. E.g. 2011-12-21") String effectiveFromString,
        @QueryParam ("effectiveTo") @ApiParam (value = "The date in ISO format or 'MAX'. E.g. 2011-12-21", defaultValue = "MAX") String effectiveToString,
        @ApiParam (value = "file to upload", required = true) @FormDataParam ("file") InputStream inputStream,
        @ApiParam (value = "file detail", required = true) @FormDataParam ("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @QueryParam ("threshold") @ApiParam(required = true, value = "Logging threshold", allowableValues = "MESSAGE,NOTICE,WARNING,ERROR", defaultValue = "WARNING") Severity threshold)
        throws IOException, Persistence.Exception, BusinessException, ConfigurationException {
    ExternalFile externalFile = new VirtualExternalFile (fileDetail.getFileName (), ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream));

    TaskExecutionJob<ExternalFile, DataLoadProcessResult> taskExecutionJob = prepareTransfer (businessUnitName, sourceSystemName, descriptor,
            EndPointHelper.getEffectivePeriodFrom (effectiveFromString, effectiveToString), externalFile, threshold);

    return EndPointHelper.createResponseFor(taskExecutionJob.executeSynchronous ());
```

Is there a parameter that I am not including and that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if someone will be stuck on similar issue i will post my working answer, maybe someone who understand better the REST architecture can explain why it needs to be done this way:

```
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("http")
            .setHost("localhost:9090")
            .setPath("warehouse-ui/api/v2/external-file/"+context.get("descriptor").toString())
            .setParameter("businessUnit", context.get("businessUnit").toString())
            .setParameter("sourceSystem", context.get("sourceSystem").toString())
            .setParameter("effectiveFrom", context.get("effectiveFrom").toString())
            .setParameter("effectiveTo", context.get("effectiveTo").toString())
            .setParameter("threshold", context.get("threshold").toString());

    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((usernamePasswordPair).getBytes());
    File isF = new File(pathToFile);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = new FileInputStream(isF);

    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(builder.toString());
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(fis, isF.getName())).build();
    request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    System.out.println(code);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
```

This is code pasted from Talend tJava component so in your code you may want to deal with exceptions.